# Как запустить таймер с нуля?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени суток. Необходимо запустить таймер с нуля минут и нуля секунд, а по нажатию на кнопку, остановить его и записать значение.

```js
var timerId;

function update() {
  var clock = document.getElementById('timer');

  var start = new Date(0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 000);

  var minutes = start.getMinutes();
  if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;
  clock.children[0].innerHTML = minutes;

  var seconds = start.getSeconds();
  if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;
  clock.children[1].innerHTML = seconds;
}

function clockStart() {
  setInterval(update, 1000);
  update();
}

clockStart();
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <span class="minutes"></span>
  <span class="seconds"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: а что делает это строка   var seconds = start.getSeconds();

Comment: @DuuudeXX8 количество секунд возвращает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вкратце, значение тайм-аута записываем в переменную, `clearTimeout` функция которая останавливает тайм-аут, в нее передаем это значение

Переменную `_start` я вынес с функции `update()` потому что, если она будет внутри функции то будет при каждом вызове создаваться новая и у нас не получится сделать таймер.

ПС: в код добавил чуть-чуть комментариев, если что непонятно, спрашивайте

Как-то так :

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var timerId;
  var _start = new Date(0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 000);
  var clock = document.getElementById('timer');

  function update() {
    _start.setSeconds(_start.getSeconds() + 1);

    var minutes = _start.getMinutes();
    if (minutes < 10) minutes = '0' + minutes;

    clock.children[0].innerHTML = minutes;

    var seconds = _start.getSeconds();
    if (seconds < 10) seconds = '0' + seconds;

    clock.children[1].innerHTML = seconds;
  }

  var start = document.querySelector('#start');
  var stop = document.querySelector('#stop');
  var reset = document.querySelector('#reset');
   
  start.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (!timerId) {
      // записываем значение нашего таймера в переменную
      timerId = setInterval(update, 1000);
    }
  });

  stop.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // останавливаем выполнение функции
    // и очищаем переменную интервала, чтобы в функции запуска проверять запущен ли таймер
    // так как clearTimeout возвращает undefined то это то что надо
    timerId = clearTimeout(timerId);       
    console.log(clock.children[0].innerHTML + ':' + clock.children[1].innerHTML);
  });
  
  reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = undefined; 
    _start = new Date(0000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 000);

    clock.children[0].innerHTML = '00';
    clock.children[1].innerHTML = '00';
  });

});
```

```html
<div id="timer">
  <span class="minutes">00</span>
  <span class="seconds">00</span>
</div>

<div>
  <button id="start">Start</button>
  <button id="stop">Stop</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
</div>
```

upd: добавил кнопку `reset`

Comment: А как запустить таймер сразу после загрузки страницы? Без нажатия на кнопку

Comment: @Stanislav вызвать эту команду `timerId = setInterval(update, 1000);`  желательно конечно после обьявления всех нужных переменных